# Graphql subscription is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I'm working on real time personal room chat application using graphql subscription node server with react client. When I tried to chat with two to three chat rooms continuously it doesn't respond . When I refreshing the page it works fine and subscription works well. I couldn't find the issue here .. Can anybody help me with this